# what are rs: and z: and ows in xml node retrieved by sharepoint webservices

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

See the following code

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
   xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
   xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <rs:data ItemCount="4">
      <z:row ows_Number_Field="6555.00000000000" 
         ows_Created="2003-06-18T03:41:09Z" 
         ows_ID="3" ows_owshiddenversion="3" />
      <z:row ows_Number_Field="78905456.0000000" 
         ows_Created="2003-06-18T17:15:58Z" 
         ows_ID="4" ows_owshiddenversion="2" />
         ...
   </rs:data>
</listitems>
```

It has tags like **rs:** ,**z:** and property like **ows**.
Is there any proper names for these values?

Answer (score 1):

- rs = RowSet
- z: ¨RowSet Shema¨(have't found a better name myself yet)
- ows: [Open Geospatial Consortium Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Geospatial_Consortium) - basically a set of standards for easier data exchange that the SharePoint WebServices follow.